# MATLAB autoencoder learning the constant function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to train a basic autoencoder in MATLAB. My data is 430 ten-dimensional points, and my autoencoder code like

```
n_features = 25;
autoenc = trainAutoencoder(data, n_features, ...
    'SparsityRegularization', 1, ...
    'SparsityProportion', 0.1, ...
    'L2WeightRegularization', 0.001, ...
    'MaxEpochs', 1000, ...
    'DecoderTransferFunction','purelin');
```

I'm using a linear decoder, as you can see. When I run this on my dataset `autoenc` ends up just learning a constant function. All the input weights end up being different but running `predict(autoenc, data)` gives the same vector for each data point. What could be going on?

Edit: I looked around some more and it seems like a common phenomenon that autoencoders sometimes learn simply the average value of the data and call it a day. Apparently it is an optimization error, and this is a local minimum. [Relevant link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123137/training-an-auto-encoder-results-in-average-output); [somewhat relevant link](https://www.quora.com/When-training-an-autoencoder-on-very-sparse-data-how-do-you-force-the-decoder-to-reconstruct-mostly-zeros-rather-than-always-just-reconstructing-the-average). Neither provide satisfactory answers. MATLAB's autoencoder only provides conjugate gradient, as far as I can tell.

Comment: These settings look pretty typical, so I wonder if there is something weird about the training data. Could you provide some more info on the data?

Comment: It's a (nonlinear) low-dimensional embedding of cell data, originally ~6500-dimensional. Ten is sufficiently many dimensions to capture at least some structure in the data; I validated this using other methods.

Comment: How does the activation of the hidden layer look? i.e. does `encode(autoenc, data)` also give the same vector for each data point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a matrix that gives same result when multiplied by a constant or another matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215481/find-a-matrix-that-gives-same-result-when-multiplied-by-a-constant-or-another-ma)